# Java converting a Window to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am trying to write some code to exit full-screen mode on a program and go into windowed mode. Currently, this is what my code looks like:

```
package main2;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class main2 extends JFrame{

    private Screen screen;

    public static void main(String args[]){

        DisplayMode dm = new DisplayMode(1900,1080,16, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
        main2 m = new main2();
        m.run(dm);

    }

    public void run(DisplayMode dm){
        setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
        setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));

        screen = new Screen();
        try{
            screen.setFullScreen(dm, this);
        }catch(Exception e){}

        getContentPane().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                super.keyTyped(e);
                screen.restoreScreen();
            }
        });

        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                super.keyTyped(e);
                screen.restoreScreen();
            }
        });

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        if(g instanceof Graphics2D){
            Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D)g;
            graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        }
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawString("some text", 200, 200);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawRect( 300,300,100,100);
    }

    private class Screen {    
        private GraphicsDevice vc;
            public Screen(){
            GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            vc = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        }

        public void setFullScreen(DisplayMode dm, JFrame window){
            window.setUndecorated(true);
            window.setResizable(false);
            vc.setFullScreenWindow(window);    
            if(dm != null && vc.isDisplayChangeSupported()){
                try{
                    vc.setDisplayMode(dm);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
                }
            }
        }

        public void restoreScreen(){
            Window w = vc.getFullScreenWindow();    
            JFrame frame = (JFrame)w;    
            if(w != null){
                w.dispose();
            }    
            vc.setFullScreenWindow(null);    
            frame.setSize(800, 600);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setLocation(10,10);
        }

        public Window getFullScreenWindow(){
            return vc.getFullScreenWindow();
        }    
    }
}
```

The program exits full-screen mode fine, but then there is not JFrame window displayed. A java icon appears on the task-bar, but no actual window appears. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it drawing off-screen? Can you try setting position as well?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I tried to do that but to no avail :(

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Comment: A MCTaRE should be one source file, and if it really needs images, it should either generate the at run-time or hot-link to them!